# Sum numbers in one cell that contains line break - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have been searching for few hours and I couldnt find any solution for this problem.

[image: See the image]

As you can see on the image I have 3 columns and 2 rows. My goal is to sum the cost row (it has line breaks) or split equipment and cost columns into 3 smaller rows. Is this possible?

Comment: IMO you should merge the department involved rows and keep equipment and cost in separate rows; then this becomes trivial. https://superuser.com/questions/1022533/is-it-possible-to-sum-numbers-separated-with-newlines-using-a-formula

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not a particularly clean way to achieve this (to my knowledge). Here are a couple of things you could try though:

**Method 1 - worksheet solution**

If your first cost cell is in A1 then place the cursor in cell B1 and create a new named range using the following formula:

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"+"))
```

You can then type the name of the named range into cell B1 and you'll get the sum as expected. Unfortunately you have to create a named range for this because `EVALUATE` isn't available as a worksheet function - only a named range function and also available in VBA.

I called my named range "eval". You can drag this formula down and it will fill down, always evaluating the cell to it's left.

[image]

---

**Method 2 - VBA solution**

You can use some simple VBA. Paste this into a new module and then use this formula on the worksheet like this:

```
=SumAlt(A1)
```

will return 600 in your example, if `A1` contained your `100 200 300`

```
Function SumAlt(s As String) As Long
    SumAlt = Evaluate(Replace(s, Chr(10), "+"))
End Function
```

Comment: When I try to do the first method is giving me alert: That function is not valid. The second method doesn't work, maybe cause I am on mac?

Comment: @StefanMarkovic, both should work fine on a Mac. I removed reference to "Sheet1" in my first formula as that is potentially not the name of your worksheet - perhaps try again now

Comment: Same as @StefanMarkovic.
More info on the EVALUATE function:
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function

Comment: I needed to use
"Chr(13) + Chr(10)"
instead of just "Chr(10)",
depends on encoding, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in VBA will work:

```
Function SumLines(ByVal str As String) As Long

    Dim arr() As String

    arr = Split(str, Chr(10))

    For a = 0 To UBound(arr)
        SumLines = SumLines + CLng(arr(a))
    Next

End Function
```

However, this will only work if you don't have any characters other than digits and Chr(10)s (new lines).

You then use this in your worksheet, e.g.:

```
=SumLines(A1)
```

Comment: This looks familiar! ;) I wouldn't return an integer because it would overflow at ~35k

Comment: You're right! I had no idea the integers in Excel were so small! Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisMack - is there any way to get this to work with currencies? When I use your function, it is only returning whole numbers and dropping the data following decimals. Thanks!

Comment: @bravesaint, according to Microsoft's documentation, you can convert a value to the Currency type by using `CCur` - so in the code I've given, use `CCur` instead of `CLng` (which is a long integer type, i.e. no decimal points). You might also try `CDec`, which is the Decimal data type, if that works better for your needs.

Comment: @ChrisMack, thank you very much! I was having issues with both `CDec` and `CCur`, but got it working after changing the integer type from `Long` to `Double` on the first line

Comment: @bravesaint, ah yes - that would also need to change - thanks!